# iPhone: How to get notification center to detect date?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just wrote an application that depends largely on the ability to notify you when a deadline is approaching. It allows the user to type in a specific date in a UITextField (not using a date picker.) I would rather not go through the hassle of setting up push notifications, iOS 5's notification center will work great. But, I'm unsure of how to get the notification center to detect the entered in dates.

I put this code in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method in my view controller:

`UILocalNotification *dateNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];`

```
            localNotif.fireDate=[NSDate date];
            localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


            localNotif.alertBody = @"Event starts in 20 minutes!";

            localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";

            localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:dateNotif];
            [localNotif release];
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here at all, I'm still really new to this. Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: Why are you registering for remote notifications if you're dead set against using push (remote) notifications?

Comment: Oh wow, yeah good point, that didn't make sense at all. I updated the OP with new code. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html), set the [`fireDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/fireDate) appropriately (and set whatever text you want the user to see), then pass it to `UIApplication`'s [`scheduleLocalNotification:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/scheduleLocalNotification%3a).

The only things you'll need to deal with beyond that are that if your app is already running when the notification fires then the notification centre won't do anything and your application delegate will get a `didReceiveLocalNotification:`. If the app isn't running but the user chooses to launch it from the alert then you'll get the local notification handed back to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, allowing you to do something relevant.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot Tommy! I updated the OP with new code, but I'm still unsure of how to get the notification to detect when the date is coming up.

Comment: Set the fireDate to the date when you want the notification to fire, not the current date. So set it to 20 minutes before whatever date the user selects (e.g. use `dateByAddingTimeInterval:-20*60` on the date the user has entered). Then the OS will do the rest for you.

Comment: Hey Tommy I have one more question, my code is now `localNotif.fireDate=[dateByAddingTimeInterval:-20*60];` What would be the proper numbers to make it fire 15 hours before? Would it be -900*60 ? And should this go in my app delegate or the specific views view controller? Thank again

Comment: Yes — the time interval is a count in seconds so -900*60 would be 15 hours earlier. 900*60 would be 15 hours later, -23 would be 23 seconds earlier, etc. Program structure is up to you, but I'd probably put it in the view controller, since it's a communication from the specific view to the model in model-view-controller terms — though in this case that part of the model is provided by the OS.